# Event for select-dropdown menu closing

Tags: javascript, events

Is there an javascript event **for the closing of an expanded dropdown** *(select-element)*?
<sub>The `blur` event [does only fire when the element loses its focus](http://jsfiddle.net/6q777mrp/1), but that seems to be independently of the dropdown.

The `change` event does only fire when the client selects an options instead of clicking somewhere else.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Try with "change" event. It will be fired when you select value from list.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it won't fire, if the user clicks outside of the select element (which also closes the dropdown)

Comment: You can also try with jQuery "focusout" event, but blur should work. Can I see your code?

Comment: There's no dropdown close event. But I found solution in other topic:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/wLWMc/

You can combine it with blur ;)